# taskqueue for deleting entities fail - python - flask - google appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, entities, task-queue, del

I don't know what I'm doing.

That's why my google appengine taskqueue isn't working.

The goal is to simply delete a million billion entities upon request ... okay.. not that many. I don't really want to succum to using mapreduce and I don't think I'll need too.  Still pretty sure that a request without a task queue implementation will time out. Hence a taskqueue.

In my case, a taskqueue that **fails. Like this:**

> INFO     2018-01-28 18:48:21,129 module.py:788] default: "POST /del/text HTTP/1.1" 302 -
>   WARNING  2018-01-28 18:48:21,129 taskqueue_stub.py:1981] Task task5 failed to execute. This task will retry in 3600.000 seconds

**Here is my wonderful failure code:**

```
@sign_in_
@app.route('/del/<entity_kind>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def DeleteStuff(entity_kind):

  allowed_deletion = {
    'text': models.Text,
  }

  cursor = None
  bookmark = request.form.get('bookmark', '')
  if bookmark:
    cursor = ndb.Cursor.from_websafe_string(bookmark)

  query = allowed_deletion[entity_kind].query()
  entries, next_cursor, more = query.fetch_page(
    1000, 
    keys_only=True,
    start_cursor=cursor)

  ndb.delete_multi(entries)

  bookmark = None
  if more:
    bookmark = next_cursor.to_websafe_string()

  taskqueue.add(
    url='/del/'+entity_kind,
    params={'bookmark': bookmark}
    )
  return "{0} deleted".format(entity_kind)
```

**However, I can't even get a task with just a return statement in it to execute:**

**in app.yaml**

```
- url: /del/*
  script: app.app
  login: admin
```

**"trigger" handler tied to app.yaml:**

```
@sign_in_
@app.route('/del/<entity_kind>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def DeleteStuff(entity_kind):

  allowed_deletion = {
    'text': models.Text,
    'call': models.Call,
    'voicemail': models.Voicemail,
    'image': models.Image,
    'email': models.Email,
  }


  taskqueue.add(
    url='/deleting/'+entity_kind,
    #params={'bookmark': bookmark}
    )
  return "{0} to be deleted".format(entity_kind)
```

**worker.yaml:**

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
service: worker

handlers:
- url: /deleting/.*
  script: worker.app
  login: admin
```

**worker.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, abort, make_response
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import datetime


from app import app
from app import models

@app.route('/deleting/<entity_kind>',methods=['POST'])
def DeletingStuff(entity_kind):

  print "entered task queue"

  allowed_deletion = {
    'text': models.Text,
    'call': models.Call,
    'voicemail': models.Voicemail,
    'image': models.Image,
    'email': models.Email,
  }
  return
```

**app structure**

```
app (folder)
    - __init__.py
    - app.py
    - worker.py
    - worker.yaml
    - app.yaml
```

maybe worker should be in it's own folder? I wouldn't know how to hook that up in flask though...

The print statement in the taskqueue isn't even firing.

all I'm getting in the terminal is stuff that says

> INFO     2018-01-28 22:11:21,432 module.py:788] default: "POST
>   /deleting/image HTTP/1.1" 302 - WARNING  2018-01-28 22:11:21,432
>   taskqueue_stub.py:1981] Task task25 failed to execute. This task will
>   retry in 409.600 seconds

**Finally, a working solution**

```
@sign_in_
@app.route('/del/<entity_type>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def DeleteStuff(entity_type):

  taskqueue.add(
    url    = "/execute_task",
    method = "POST",
    params = {
      "entity_type": entity_type,
    }
  ) # from 'from google.appengine.api import taskqueue'
  return Response("sending {} task to queue... Check logs".format(entity_type), mimetype='text/plain', status=200)#Response from 'from Flask import Response'


@sign_in_
@app.route('/execute_task', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def execute_task():
  allowed_deletion = {
    'a': models.SomemodelA,
    'b': models.SomemodelB,
    'c': models.SomemodelC,
    'd': models.SomemodelD,
  }
  entity_type = request.form.get("entity_type", '')
  bookmark = request.form.get('bookmark', '')

  cursor = None
  if bookmark:
    cursor = ndb.Cursor.from_websafe_string(bookmark)

  if entity_type:
    query = allowed_deletion[entity_type].query()
    entries, next_cursor, more = query.fetch_page(
      1000, 
      keys_only=True,
      start_cursor=cursor)

    ndb.delete_multi(entries)

    bookmark = None
    if more:
      bookmark = next_cursor.to_websafe_string()

      taskqueue.add(
        url='/execute_task',
        params={'entity_type': entity_type, 'bookmark': bookmark}
      )

  return Response("did it. You'll never see this message", mimetype='text/plain', status=200)
```

**notes**

@sign_in_ can be on the task as well without throwing errors

Google app engine throws failure errors with variable urls for task-queues, in other words this will throw failure errors:

```
@app.route('/execute_task/<some_variable>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def execute_task(some_variable):
    pass
```

both urls are listed in app.yaml, no need for worker.py and worker.yaml

```
- url: /del/*
  script: app.app
  login: admin
- url: /execute_task
  script: app.app
  login: admin
```

Many thanks to GAEfan for helping!! :)
Also Note: I was able to debug my way to the solution starting over from his code given in another post of mine: [simple google app engine taskqueue tutoral? flask / python / GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492341/simple-google-app-engine-taskqueue-tutoral-flask-python-gae/48494715#48494715)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with:

```
@app.route('/del/<entity_kind>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
```

Next, `request.args` is for a query string.  You want to handle the `POST` params:

```
request.form.get('bookmark', '')
```

Next, your `@sign_in_` tag is causing a redirect for the task queue to a signin page.  (See the `302` referenced in the error log?).  Remove that.  Try adding this to your app.yaml:

```
- url: /del/.*
  script: whereisapplication.app
  login: admin
```

That will put it behind your Google login, but the task queue still can access.

**Update to your update:**

A print statement from a task is meaningless;  You will never see it.  Try:

```
import logging
logging.info("{0} to be deleted".format(entity_kind))
```

or:

```
@app.route('/deleting/<entity_kind>/',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/deleting/<entity_kind>',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def DeletingStuff(entity_kind):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print "here"
```

and see if you can access the url in the browser.  Note trailing slash in 1st route: to help diagnose the redirect issue.

You could also skip the `POST` method completely, and use a query string:

`/deleting/text?cursor=387123481246123469`

`cursor = request.args.get("cursor", None)`

Comment: yep. trying that currently. I'm not getting any more warnings. Just need to make sure it's actually working.

Comment: "You want to handle the POST params".. really? It's gonna be in a form? You're sure? I"ll try it.

Comment: still getting error warnings INFO     2018-01-28 19:55:46,496 module.py:788] default: "POST /del/text HTTP/1.1" 302 -
WARNING  2018-01-28 19:55:46,496 taskqueue_stub.py:1981] Task task6 failed to execute. This task will retry in 6.400 seconds

Comment: there must be something I need to add to a yaml file or something?

Comment: well, I can get that handler to  execute with the sign in directive. The task does fail however, so I put the actual task in another file without the sign in directive, yet, it won't even execute a print statement (See edited post above) so I must be missing something pretty big.

Comment: (p.s. what you suggested for app.yaml was already there, although, the sign_in_ directive was still there. I can at least try doing what you suggested by removing just to rule out that as being the issue)

Comment: (yep. just ruled out the @sign_in_ directive being the issue, because I'm still getting fails with the original 'improved' code (not in worker.py, but in app.py and removing the directive)

Comment: slowly working up from the answer you gave here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492341/simple-google-app-engine-taskqueue-tutoral-flask-python-gae/48494715#48494715 , the problem was having a taskqueue with a varied url / route (along with the things you identified previously). Thus '/del/<entity_kind>' was throwing failures for this post, while '/execute_task/<entity_kind>' would throw failure errors for the other post. I had to get  the entity_kind from the post parameters instead.(currently I'm working on getting back to most of the original code)

Comment: finally a working solution (see above) thanks for your help!! :)